# Map list of Options to list of Strings

Tags: kotlin, option-type, arrow-kt

I've been using Arrow Kotlin quite a lot recently but I'm still confused on how to map a list of options to their values. For example:

```
val listOfStrings: List<String> = listOf<Option<String>>().map { /* ? */ }
```

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
val listOfStrings: List<String> = listOf<Option<String>>().filter { it.isDefined() }.map { it.getOrElse { "" } }
```

But it feels clunky and I'm surely missing something.

Comment: Doesn't look too clunky to me.

Comment: @TomH I'm already filtering by `isDefined()`, shouldn't be calling `getOrElse`.

Comment: With a line break before the map and proper indentation I think this is completely fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want Haskell's `catMaybes`. :D
I don't know if there's something similar in Arrow, but you could use `filterMap` from `arrow.core.extensions.list.monadFilter.filterMap`:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(Some(1), None)

    println(list.filterMap(::identity))
}
// prints: ListK(list=[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I believe Kotlin's nullable support is able to handle nullable with more grace that arrow Option, check [blogpost](https://medium.com/@jcamilorada/kotlin-nullable-type-vs-java-optional-arrow-option-58751116c399), Said that some alternatives would be:

```
listOf<Option<String>>().mapNotNull { it.orNull() }
listOf<Option<String>>().flatMap { it.toList() }
listOf<Option<String>>().mapNotNull { if (it is Some) it.t else null }
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid `mapNotNull` but it definitely seems the more elegant solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to extract a value from an `Option` you need to provide a default value in case the value is *absent*.

In the second line of code you're using `getOrElse` for that. Which is correct and has a signature of `fun <A> Option<A>.getOrElse(f: () -> A): A` which means it either returns the *present* value or the default value in case of *absence*.

Solution:
You can simply `map` every `Option` in your `List` to a value using `getOrElse`.

```
val listOfStrings: List<String> = listOf<Option<String>>().map { it.gerOrElse { "" }  }
```

Comment: No, I don't want the empty values, that's why I'm filtering first.